# NGINX Config: How to redirect array of URLs to home page

Tags: redirect, nginx, configuration, config

I would like an array of URLs, let's say `['/about','/supported-software', '/the-team', ...]` to simply redirect to `/`.

Do I need to write multiple `location { }` blocks?

I'm new to NGINX configuration so any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I would use multiple prefix locations. If you got lots of them, you could try a map with an included file containing the URLs.

Comment: Hi @ColeTierney, thanks a lot for your response. Do you mind providing me with an example?

Comment: I've added an answer with a couple ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array entries are exact matches, then the following locations should give you the best performance:

```
location = /about { return 301 $scheme://$host; }
location = /supported-software { return 301 $scheme://$host; }
location = /the-team { return 301 $scheme://$host; }
# ... or put these in an included file
```

If they are not exact matches, a map may be better:

```
map $uri $send_home {
    ~^/about/?  1;
    ~^/supported-software/? 1;
    ~^/the-team/?   1;
    # ... or put these in an included file
}

server {
    # ...

    if ($send_home) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host;
    }

    # ...
}
```

The map would allow more flexible redirects like:

```
/about
/about/
/about/stuff
```